# Switch between columns' active tabs in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublime-text-2

I know Sublime Text makes the following commands available:

```
ctrl+tab and ctrl+shift+tab - navigate through recent tabs

ctrl+pageup and ctrl+pagedown - navigate through adjacent tabs
```

I usually keep three columns each holding a group of related files, but normally I'm only actively using one file out of each of these columns (thus such a layout).

I understand there's Go to Anything but it opens the file in my current column even if it's already open in another column (it could simply switch to the open file's tab).

So what keybinding could I use to quickly navigate to the active tab in each column?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>3</kbd> to switch between the panels.

You can also use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> - <kbd>3</kbd> to move the current tab to another panel.

To create or drop multiple panes <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd>.

Comment: Do you know of a way to move the tab within the current panel? i.e. there are two tabs, I want to switch them round. (and not use the mouse!)

Comment: @IanVaughan try https://github.com/SublimeText/MoveTab